# Netsuite integration with Visual Studio Online

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, netsuite

My company is using Netsuite to track defects and requests. I would like to use Visual Studio online to keep track of my sprint and port the defects and requests into the backlog. Is this possible?

Comment: David. Can I contact you to discuss how you are using NetSuite to track defects? We are about to set this up next week and your experiences would be helpful. jjorczak @ mrmgroup.com

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [VSO's Service Hooks](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/service-hooks/create-subscription).